# Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat' with the alpha property

Tags: swift, uikit, swift2, uiviewanimation, cgfloat

I am debugging a dropdown menu I converted from Objective-C. In it, I have this function:

```
func showMenu() {
        self.menu.hidden = false
        self.menu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        closedMenuShape.removeFromSuperlayer()

        if shouldDisplayDropShape {
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(openMenuShape)
        }

        // Set new origin of menu
        var menuFrame: CGRect = self.menu.frame
        menuFrame.origin.y = self.menubar.frame.size.height - self.offset()


        var containerAlpha: CGFloat = fadeAlpha

        if SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN("7.0") {
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(.EaseInOut)
            self.menu.frame = menuFrame
            self.container.alpha(containerAlpha) <======= Error
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4,
                                delay: 0.0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
                initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
                              options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                                self.menu.frame = menuFrame
                                self.container.alpha(containerAlpha) <==== Error

                }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
             })
           }

        UIView.commitAnimations()

    }
```

In there I have marked were the error is showing up, on the lines were `self.container.alpha(containerAlpha)` is.  The error says `Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat'`, and this is the declaration for container:

```
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIImageView!
```

I have imported `UIKit`. What would be causing this error?

Let me now if you need more information.

Comment: You should set it like `self.container.alpha = containerAlpha`, since `alpha` is a property, you should assign to it

Comment: @DánielNagy. Thanks, it worked. Why did you answer the question in a comment?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure, but I'm happy it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `UIImageView` has an alpha property (not a method), you need to assign the alpha value to the `UIImageView`, like this:

```
 self.container.alpha = containerAlpha
```

On the other hand; if `UIImageView` *did* have an alpha method, you would use

```
self.container.alpha(containerAlpha)
```