# Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat' - Xcode -

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a button that when pressed starts a game. Where it says `let pointOfTouch = touch.location(self)`, I am getting the error message "Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat.'" There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945625/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-cgfloat-with-the-alpha-property) regarding this, but I have not found much use from it. Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(self)
        let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeITapped.name == "startGame" {
            startGame()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `touch.location(in: self)` help? You are using Swift 3?

Comment: Why do you annotate a concrete type (`UITouch`) as unspecified (`AnyObject`)? This is not Objective-C. Don't make it worse. Delete the annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
```